# Can I make the chrome browser show every json row in a separated line?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, google-chrome

My controller/action end like this:

```
    JsonResult jsonResult = Json(carList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    jsonResult.MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue;
    return jsonResult;
}
```

Im debuging the JSON return by my webservice. but if the window is maximized is very hard to read.

[image]

In other hand, if I reduce the windows width size the result is much easier to read.

[image]

Is there a way I can make the JSON result show in separated lines each row without resizing?

Comment: if it isn't sensitive data you can use a javascript/json beautifier. just google it

Comment: @AndreaConte But in that case I have to make a View ?

Comment: nope, you have just to copy paste your json in one of those sites

Answer (score 1, accepted):

View the JSON resource with Developer Tools (F12) open. In the *Network* tab, select the JSON resource on the left and click the *Preview* tab on the right. This will nicely format the response for you, allowing you to expand and collapse each object.

[image]

Comment: if I left click the link from `Network` tab go to the `Sources` tab. Then suggest I click `{}` to preatty format, but nothing change. And I cant find the `Preview` tab.

Comment: You shouldn't be on the *Sources* tab - just the *Network* tab. See screenshot.

Comment: Yes, that is perfect, I did right click instead of left click.

Answer (score 0):

There is a chrome plugin called "Json Viewer" (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/json-viewer/gbmdgpbipfallnflgajpaliibnhdgobh) that I use quite frequently. I believe there exist many plugins like that on the market, I just found this tool to come in very handy for debugging json responses.

Hope this helps

Comment: is nice, but then put every field in a different line, so is also harder to compare between rows.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the following extension, that does the job beautifully
:https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/json-formatter/bcjindcccaagfpapjjmafapmmgkkhgoa?hl=en

Comment: is nice, but then put every field in a different line, so is also harder to compare between rows.